# magento 1.10 unable to upload image

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I have tried to save the image in product page in Magento 1.10, but give me this type of error:
`jquery this.images.toJson() not a function`.

Please See this screenshot

[image]

Please help me find the solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaced this.images.toJson() to JSON.stringify(this.images) , it works fine now